# RCP application deployed through WebStart

Tags: eclipse-rcp, java-web-start

I am just trying to get one  sample RCP application (Hello RCP) to be launched through WebStart. And it looks like it tries to download and gives me the security message about certificates (I have signed the  jars with 3rd party certificates). It also gives me message about "Block" / "Unblock". 
[image: Warning messages from Java while RCP loads]

On the final one when I click "Don't Block" or "Block" , the java console that is open just closes . I cheked the .trace files in the deployment folder  but there is no exception/error that I could see.
The application RCP is a basic RCP application that we can create in Eclipse by selecting the Hello RCP  template. I have not done any modification to that.

I am using JRE 1.7 update 51 but did try 1.6 update 17 as well. Also I used JDK 1.7/ JDK 1.6  update to build this application but same results. Why I am clueless is because there is no error message  that points me to what is wrong.
I tried one AWT application to launch through RCP and that launches fine. I just followed some articles over internet to create the application and deploy and it is my first attempt to launch it through WS  so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Any help is much appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Make sure your program doesn't launch immediately into a background thread. I've experienced `SwingWorker` causing the program to close before it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation on the new security udpates for Java7 Update51](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/entry/java_se_7_update_51).

You can no longer use selft-sign certificates.  There are also some changes you need to make in the MANIFEST.MF, without which, will cause your application to be blocked.

Comment: Thanks I am using 3rd party certificates .  In the jnlp file I have only the default  <all-permissions>  given under <security> .

Comment: Take a look at this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html and see if you have complied with all these new requirements.